# Using SimpleCursorAdapter with Spinner?

Tags: android, android-cursor, simplecursoradapter

I have a db with table "mytable" having 2 colums "id","sampletext"
I want to query distinct values of sampletext and feed to a Spinner using SimpleCursorAdapter.

here is what is tried

```
String[] cols=new String[]{"sampletext"};
int[] lbls=new lbls[]{android.R.id.text1};
mycursor=sdb.query(true,"mytable", cols,null,null,null,null,null,null);
sca=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mycursor, cols,lbls,0);
sca.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spn.setAdapter(sca);
```

When i run this i get error at line 4 :  id does not exist. 
when i changed first line to "id" the spinner got populated with id values.
But i need "sampletext", what am i doing wrong?
Appreciate any suggestions

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
what am i doing wrong
```

you didnt read documentation ...

there are two arrays of string with columns: first in used in query, second one in Adapter constructor(you used only one array for both)

first one tells sqlite which columns should be taken to Cursor, second tells Adapter which ones should be showed/mapped to Views in single row...

Next `CursorAdapter` needs `Cursor` with column named `_id`

So now it's pretty obvious that we should do smthin like this:

```
String[] queryCols=new String[]{"_id", "sampletext"};
String[] adapterCols=new String[]{"sampletext"};
int[] adapterRowViews=new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
mycursor=sdb.query(true,"mytable", queryCols,null,null,null,null,null,null);
sca=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mycursor, adapterCols, adapterRowViews,0);
sca.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spn.setAdapter(sca);
```

Comment: Sorry abt that , should have checked the docs more properly.. I dont have the errors but there is a different logical issue. Since _id is a primary key when i use query DISTINCT i end up with all the rows in the cursor. Any suggestions?

Comment: do not sorry :) ... i understand that it takes time to get knowledge about new platform ... i hope that this answer was helpful for you :)

Comment: its hard to say how we can help you if we do not know what `sdb.query` does ... im pretty sure that `sdb` is not an instance of `SQLiteDatabase` but rather it is some kind of your own helper class

Comment: sdb is instance of sqlitedatabase, i created a table with dummy values and trying to populate a spinner with distinct values from one of the columns using CursorAdapter.

Comment: it seems like you're database is not planned well ... i think there should be 2 tables one for similar rows as you have now `table1(_id, col1, col3, sampletext_but_not_as_text_as__id_from_second_table)` and second table with `table2(_id, sampletext_value_text)` ... for spinner you're using `table2` ... Selvin out!(have no time)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example with raw query. Please note the first ID column returned by the query should be labeled as `_id` .

MyDatabase.java:

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
     ...
    public Cursor getListNamesForDropDown() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String sql = "select ID _id, Name from MyTable order by Name ";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;
    }
```

MyActivity.java:

```
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....    
           Cursor cursorTest =  db.getListNamesForDropDown();
           android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter  adapter = new android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    cursorTest, 
                    new String[] {"Name"}, 
                    new int[] {android.R.id.text1}, 0);       
           adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
           spinnerTest.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            cursor,
            new String[] { DBOpenHelper.ACCOUNT_BANK },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }, 0);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```