# What's the best structure to store Public Transport data?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to solve a problem, how to store Public Transport data efficiently for obtaining and representing it in Android. The simplified use of my class is this: user select the bus number using spinner, then he selects the stop at specified street (also using spinner). And after that he clicks the submit button and the timetable of the bus at specified street shows up in the fragment below the submit button. The main question is: what's the best structure to store Public Transport data? Three dimensional array, HashMap, Map or something else? You can find a live example here: http://marijampolietis.balsas.lt/miesto-autobusu-tvarkarastis/
P.S. Right now, I'm storing both spinners data in strings.xml array

Comment: Having not thought about your project at all, I can assure you that three dimensional array is not the correct choice.

Comment: So can we assume that the list of streets to select from will be a different list for each bus number?

Comment: In fact no, they will be the same for all. But just for case of interest, I wonder how to deal with both variants

Answer (score 0):

My guess is a good solution for your scenario would be to store the data in a SQLite DB. See reference here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Comment: But isn't it too complex for constant buses and streets selection? Though I agree that it suits with timetables well

Comment: You could keep all the data in the DB and link it with the spinners using CursorAdapters on app initialization. Yes, the DB storage choice fits perfectly for timetable data.

Comment: See answer to this question for a sample of CursorAdapter use in a Spinner: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413030/using-simplecursoradapter-with-spinner